# Kotlin Regex Boundary Matching Not working

Tags: regex, kotlin, regular-language

I'm trying to parse a word, bounded by whitespace or punctuation on either side.

I tried this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val regex = "\bval\b".toRegex();
    regex.matches("fn foo() { val x = 2;} x;").also { println(it) }
}
```

But this prints out false. I tested the regex on here https://regex101.com/r/vNBefF/2 and it works, matching against the input string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong method. From the [KotlinDoc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/matches.html):

> Indicates whether the regular expression matches the entire input.

I think what you may want is [containsMatchIn](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/contains-match-in.html).  You can play with this on the [playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjMxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJmb2xkZWRCdXR0b24iOnRydWUsInJlYWRPbmx5IjpmYWxzZSwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKGFyZ3M6IEFycmF5PFN0cmluZz4pIHtcbiAgICB2YWwgcmVnZXggPSBcIlwiXCJcXGJ2YWxcXGJcIlwiXCIudG9SZWdleCgpO1xuICAgIHJlZ2V4LmNvbnRhaW5zTWF0Y2hJbihcImZuIGZvbygpIHsgdmFsIHggPSAyO30geDtcIikuYWxzbyB7IHByaW50bG4oaXQpIH1cbn0ifQ==).

Comment: Great! On my case it was `contains("YOUR_REGEX".toRegex())`